# Retrieving a value in one class that is set in a different class

Tags: c#, class

I am having an issue with retrieving a value from a separate class. I have a string variable in a class named **Alpha** where I want the value to be changed to what is entered by the user in my **Bravo()** method.

For the second class named **Charlie**, I want to use the same value entered by the user. I understand why my work doesn't work but I have no idea if I am missing something fundamental to make it work.

**Code:**

```
    class Alpha
    {
        public string message = "hello.";

        public void Bravo()
        {
            Charlie charlie = new Charlie();

            Console.WriteLine("Enter message here:");
            message = Console.ReadLine();

            Console.WriteLine("Alpha() says, " + message + ".");

            charlie.Delta();
        }
    }

    class Charlie
    {
        public void Delta()
        {
            Alpha alpha = new Alpha();

            Console.WriteLine("Charlie() says, " + alpha.message);
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Alpha alpha = new Alpha();
            alpha.Bravo();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to pass the alpha instance to charlie

```
    charlie.Delta(this);
```

and

```
    public void Delta(Alpha alpha)
    {

        Console.WriteLine("Charlie() says, " + alpha.message);
    }
```

this is because you can have multiple different alphas with different messages. In your currebt code you creat a new alpha that has nothing to do with the one that called charlie.delta.

Another possibility is to have static data. In this case there is only one occurrence of it

```
class Alpha
{
    public static string message = "hello.";
    .....

    public void Bravo()
    {
        Charlie charlie = new Charlie();

        Console.WriteLine("Enter message here:");
        Alpha.message = Console.ReadLine();

        Console.WriteLine("Alpha() says, " + message + ".");

        charlie.Delta();
    }
}
```

and

```
    public void Delta()
    {
     

        Console.WriteLine("Charlie() says, " + Alpha.message);
    }
```

Comment: Wow this seems very obvious in hindsight. Thank you so much this is perfect, I hope you have a lekker day.

Comment: @Brad and I hope to find out what 'lekker' means. Or is it a typo?

Answer (score 0):

You could also extract the code to read/write the message in a third class and pass it as a dependency to **Alpha** and **Charlie**.

```
class Message
{
    private string _message = "hello.";

    public void Read()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Enter message here:");
        _message = Console.ReadLine();
    }

    public void Write(string from)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"{from}() says ,{_message}");
    }
}
```

And then update the rest like:

```
class Alpha
{
    private readonly Message _message;
    private readonly Charlie _charlie;

    public Alpha(Message message)
    {
        _message = message;
        _charlie = new Charlie(message);
    }

    public void Bravo()
    {
        _message.Write(nameof(Alpha));
        _charlie.Delta();
    }
}

class Charlie
{
    private readonly Message _message;

    public Charlie(Message message)
    {
        _message = message;
    }

    public void Delta()
    {
        _message.Write(nameof(Charlie));
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Message message = new Message();
        message.Read();
        
        Alpha alpha = new Alpha(message);
        alpha.Bravo();
    }
}
```